# Presenting Two UIViewControllers , One for landscape and one for portrait is possible?

Tags: ios, iphone

New to ios , have a dashboard screen , with many UIObjects , so created a landscape view controller in storyboard. Now i want present portrait view controller and landscape view controller , depends on orientation.

Comment: Better you use the same view controller

Comment: If don't want to use Autolayout then use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation for changing layout.Set frames and other UI in this method.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good way to implementing.

use single viewcontroller add two uiview on base viewcontroller as per your design.

or

AutoLayout only available on ios 6 and above

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

There is something called as Autolayout  and Constraints for presenting a single viewcontroller for both orientations

Constraints is a bit of advanced. Try to acquire some knowledge about the Autoresizingmasks and apply the Autolayout to your views.

Autolayout can reduce a lot of code.

It was beautifully explained here. Check this out
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

OfCourse you can do it by using the following code

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || self.interfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
    //Hide the portrait view and show the Landscape view
        [self.Portraitview setHidden:YES];
        [self.Landscapeview setHidden:NO];
}
else if (self.interfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    //Show the portrait view and Hide the Landscape view
        [self.Portraitview setHidden:NO];
        [self.Landscapeview setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use two separate view for two orientations this will cause huge memory consumption the using single viewController. always use single view controller. it ur not familiar with autolayout the just note down the actual frame of view in landscape mode then set it in viewdidlayout or viewwilllayout method.